# Specifying a layout file in Sails.js when calling sails.renderView

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs

I'm using the sails helper method `sails.renderView` to render a view into a string that is then used in an email, like so:

```
sails.renderView('emails/booking', emailData, function (err, view) {
    emailService.send(user.email, view);
});
```

Is it possible to specify a layout file when rendering a view in this way? I'm using ejs template engine.

It doesn't look like I can use the view config (`config/views.js`) as it's route based.

I had a look at the render function in `sails/lib/hooks/views/render.js` and it looked like the layout file to use could be passed in the options object but when I did, no view is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry I missed that this is being generated outside the regular request/response context. Answer changed to reflect that.

I had a poke through the sails code, particularly [the render engine](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/867c1627be269315092061649f87359e2cc16a1a/lib/hooks/views/render.js)

```
/**
 * sails.hooks.views.render(relPathToView, options, cb_view)
 *
 * @param {String} relPathToView
 *              -> path to the view file to load (minus the file extension)
 *                  relative to the app's `views` directory
 * @param {Object} options
 *              -> options hash to pass to template renderer, including locals and locale
 * @param {Function} cb_view(err)
 *              -> called when the view rendering is complete (response is already sent, or in the process)
 *                  (probably should be @api private)
 * @api public
 */
... lots of code ... 
  // if local `layout` is set to true or unspecified
  // fall back to global config
  var layout = options.layout;
  if (layout === undefined || layout === true) {
    layout = sails.config.views.layout;
  }
```

Turns out you can set the layout as part of the options object you pass into `sails.renderView()`

So if you have an email template `emailLayout.ejs`, you can use it by adding this line to you controller like so:

```
emailData.layout = '/emailLayout';
sails.renderView('emails/booking', emailData, function (err, view) {
    emailService.send(user.email, view);
});
```

Big caveat, this explicitly only works for `ejs` templates.
I haven't tested this, so let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks Frederick. I should've said, this method isn't getting called in response to a HTTP request so I don't have a response object that I can set the layout file.

Comment: Yeah that got it, thanks. I did try specifying the layout in the options object before but realised I had the path wrong. It needs to be "/emailLayout" if it's in the root views folder not just "emailLayout". Cheers.

Comment: Well thats an annoying little thing! Glad it helped